# Passing record into Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create an aggregate function that takes a set of records, does some calculations, and returns a number.

I have gotten the following dummy example to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_func(text) RETURNS int    
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    rec record;
    num int := 0;
  BEGIN
     FOR rec IN EXECUTE $1
     LOOP
         IF POSITION('some text' IN rec.known_column_name) = 1
         THEN
           num := num + 1;
         END IF;
     END LOOP;
     RETURN num;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

If I enter

```
SELECT dummy_func('select * from some_table');
```

, it works as expected.

However, I would like to make it so that I can use multiple functions and conditions, such as:

```
SELECT conditional_col_1, dummy_func_1(*), dummy_func_2(*)
FROM some_table
WHERE conditional_col_2 = 'some val'
GROUP BY 1
```

How can I rewrite my dummy example into being able to function as so (or use a bunch of UNIONS ALL, etc)?

**In response to Hambone**

If I have the following logic (counting 'a' or counting 'b' * column something3)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_a(text) RETURNS int
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    rec record;
    num int := 0;
  BEGIN
     FOR rec IN EXECUTE $1
     LOOP
        num := num + length(regexp_replace(rec.something1, '[^a]+', '', 'g'));
     END LOOP;
     RETURN num;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_e_times_something3(text) RETURNS int
AS
$$
  DECLARE
    rec record;
    num int := 0;
  BEGIN
     FOR rec IN EXECUTE $1
     LOOP
        num := num + length(regexp_replace(rec.something1, '[^e]+', '', 'g')) * rec.something3::int;
     END LOOP;
     RETURN num;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I currently have to execute them individually,

```
$=# SELECT count_a('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST WHERE something2 = ''A'' and something1 = ''0'''); 
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count_a | 0

$=# SELECT count_a('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST WHERE something2 = ''A'' and something3 = ''0'''); 
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count_a | 2

$=# SELECT count_e_times_something3('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST WHERE something2 = ''A'' and something3 = ''0''');
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------+--
count_e_times_something3 | 0

$=# SELECT count_e_times_something3('SELECT * FROM MY_TEST WHERE something2 = ''A'' and something3 = ''1''');
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------+--
count_e_times_something3 | 7
```

It would be a lot nicer if I could use the following query (I know I need to define an Aggregate function but I can't find any examples where records are taken in an scalars are returned):

```
SELECT something2, count_a(*), count_e_times_something3(*) FROM MY_TEST WHERE something3 = '1';

something: 'A'
count_a: 3
count_e_times_something3: 7

something: 'B'
count_a: 3
count_e_times_something3: 2
```

Both count_a resulting in 3 is a coincidence

Comment: I'm almost there, but not quite...  can you show a use case or two with sample input and desired output?

Comment: Also, I realize that in this example, the input is text. But for my actual use case I need to pass rows that maintain their types. For example a quarterback's plays so that I can compute completion rate, yards per completion, total yards, etc.

Comment: You don't need a custom function for that, this can also be achieved with pure SQL